# Oracle oci.dll was not found and sqlException 32104 :)

Tags: c++, sql, oracle, occi

I have oracle 64bit sqldeveloper and 64bit instantclient_12_2 installld with 2022VS community, the occi.h library seems to be working since there are no errors in code.[image]

NOTE: I do include username and pass, didn't want to share here.

Here is the files in project.

[image]

and this is the output when executed.

[image]

So I though I would include oci.dll in project folder.

[image]

And this is the new output.

[image]

I also did update my drivers.
what can I do to be able to connect?

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots. Use formatted text, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Comment: Did you compile the code as "x64" (or "AnyCPU")?

Comment: yea it was release x64

Comment: Maybe add folder of `oci.dll` to your `PATH` environment variable.

Answer (score -1):

I just copy pasted all .dll files to project folder.